# Changing Framerate & System.Threading Aforge.video C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, frame-rate, aforge

I have a small project whereby I capture images from a webcam and decode the qr.

The following code captures an image and stores it to a local file, *but* only when it is not in the while loop. The system.threading appears to make the captured image just black. If i don't use it(the loop), it captures far too many images a second.

**So is there a way of changing the aforge.video framerate so that i can capture an image every x seconds without while loop?**

```
   public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public int FrameRate { get; set; }

    private FilterInfoCollection VideoCaptureDevices;
    private VideoCaptureDevice FinalVideo;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        inputDevices.Items.Clear();

        VideoCaptureDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
        foreach (FilterInfo VideoCaptureDevice in VideoCaptureDevices)
        {
            inputDevices.Items.Add(VideoCaptureDevice.Name);
        }
        inputDevices.SelectedIndex = 0;     
    }

    public void Start_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FinalVideo = new VideoCaptureDevice(VideoCaptureDevices[inputDevices.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
        FinalVideo.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalVideo_NewFrame);
        FinalVideo.Start();
    }
    void FinalVideo_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 10)
        {
            Bitmap video = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
            video.Save("C:\\Users\\Wayneio\\Desktop\\image\\test" + i + ".jpg");
            i++;
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }

    }
    public void Stop_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.FinalVideo.Stop();
    }
}
```

Additionally I get this error when trying to stop the capture via the asp button:

```
 Object reference not set to an instance of an object on this.FinalVideo.Stop();
```

Tried this to no avail:
     ((VideoCaptureDevice)FinalVideo).DesiredFrameRate = 10;

Answer (score -1):

before you code start video set the framreate like this

```
 FinalVideo.DesiredFrameRate = 10;
 FinalVideo.Start();
```

Another option to skip frames that you save is to use a function that is not always true
if you have a global counter value  myCounter

do a modulo calulation like below ix mycounter devided by 10 equals 1

```
 myCounter++
 if (m(ycounter %% 10))==1) { //code to save your bitmap   }
```

Comment: `FinalVideo.DesiredFrameRate` is [obsolete](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/f9b0abf6-be44-6d8f-cac9-1cbf8fbd5a8c.htm) `"...Setting this property does not have any effect."`

Comment: your right that is unless your using an older version.
since my app was builded around an older version, to me it has no benneift to rewrite the whole app, just to support a new aforge version since a lot has changed between those versions.

Comment: That's fair enough - we all have code like that - I'm just pointing out that for new development, it might not be what the OP is looking for

Comment: well i think his syntax is using the other old methods too. perhaps he worked based upon sme older code samples